# How to debug my if and elif statements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Kinematics clculator

print('Kinematics Calculator')

print('If either one of the three values(s,v,t) is not given then put its value = 1')


s = float(input('Enter your distance =  '))
print(s)


t = float(input('Enter your time =  '))
print(t)


v = float(input('Enter your velocity =  '))
print(v)


if 'v == 1' :
    print('velocity = '+ str(s/t))

elif 't == 1' :
    print('time = '+ str(s/v))

else :
     's == 1' 
print('distance = '+ str(v*t))
```

Help me correct this code. Whenever I try to calculate anything else than "velocity" it always uses the first print command i.e

```
print('velocity = '+ str(s/t))
```

Comment: You should indent it `print('velocity = '+ str(s/t))`

Comment: `'v == 1'` and siblings are _strings_.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: A good question will always contain a description of what you expected, and what actually happened, when the program is run. Also, please do not shout - questions that need editing work tend to get downvoted quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'v == 1'` always evaluates to true, because it's a non-empty string. You should use

```
if v == 1:
    print('velocity = '+ str(s/t))

elif t == 1:
    print('time = '+ str(s/v))

else:
     print('distance = '+ str(v*t))
```